# ExpandBar in Eclipse View Part

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add an expand bar to an Eclipse viewpart. When I click the expand button I would like the viewpart to move items below the expand bar down and show the expanded items. What currently happens is the expand bar items just disappear below the items below the expand bar. Any thoughts?

```
final ExpandBar expandBar = new ExpandBar(parent, SWT.NONE);
expandBar.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW));
expandBar.setSpacing(0);
fd_toolBar.top = new FormAttachment(expandBar, 6);
FormData fd_expandBar = new FormData();
fd_expandBar.top = new FormAttachment(0, 62);
fd_expandBar.left = new FormAttachment(0, 3);
expandBar.setLayoutData(fd_expandBar);
formToolkit.paintBordersFor(expandBar);

final ExpandItem xpndtmWarningDetails = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
xpndtmWarningDetails.setExpanded(true);
xpndtmWarningDetails.setText("Warning Details");

final Composite composite_1 = new Composite(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
composite_1.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));
xpndtmWarningDetails.setControl(composite_1);
formToolkit.paintBordersFor(composite_1);
xpndtmWarningDetails.setHeight(xpndtmWarningDetails.getControl().computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);

Label lblTest = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
lblTest.setBounds(10, 10, 55, 15);
lblTest.setText("Test");

expandBar.addExpandListener(new ExpandListener(){

    @Override
    public void itemCollapsed(ExpandEvent e) {
        expandBar.setSize(expandBar.getSize().x, xpndtmWarningDetails.getHeaderHeight());
        parent.layout(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemExpanded(ExpandEvent e) {
        expandBar.setSize(expandBar.getSize().x, 300);
        expandBar.layout(true);
        parent.layout(true);
    }

});
```

Comment: share your code, so that it will be easy to understand what you are talking

Comment: Here is my code example. I have it so my other items in my view move according to the expanding of this bar but my data in my composite does not re-appear on an expand.

Comment: I tried using your code to reproduce the issues you describe, but there are things missing in your code that prevent me from doing so. I tried to copy and paste your code into a simple Composite object's constructor, but the variables fd_toolbar and formToolkit are not defined anywhere in the code you've provided. I could guess how to get them defined, but I'd rather know how you're doing it in your code.

Comment: I have your code working in my basic Composite object but I'm not seeing the issue you're having.  I'm wondering if you could share a little more code so I can see the part of the UI that is being hidden. when the expand bar is expanded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the ExpandBar works best when used like it is in this example...

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet343.java

... with several expand bars stacked on top of each other, and nothing else mixed in.

I think the functionality your looking for can be accomplished with an ExpandableComposite object.  It depends on what else is going on in your ViewPart.

Here's a quick example of an ExpandableComposite.

```
package com.amx.designsuite.rcp;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ScrolledForm;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.TableWrapLayout;

public class ExpandableCompositeExample extends Composite {

/**
 * Create the composite.
 * @param parent
 * @param style
 */
public ExpandableCompositeExample(final Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);
    FormToolkit toolkit;

    toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
    final ScrolledForm form = toolkit.createScrolledForm(parent);
    form.setText("Title for Form holding Expandable Composite (optional)");
    TableWrapLayout layout = new TableWrapLayout();
    form.getBody().setLayout(layout);

    ExpandableComposite expandableCompsite = toolkit.createExpandableComposite(form.getBody(), ExpandableComposite.TREE_NODE | ExpandableComposite.SHORT_TITLE_BAR);
    toolkit.paintBordersFor(expandableCompsite);
    expandableCompsite.setText("Expandable Composite Title (Optional)");
    expandableCompsite.setExpanded(true);

    Text txtMyNewText = toolkit.createText(expandableCompsite, "Text to show when composite is expanded", SWT.NONE);
    expandableCompsite.setClient(txtMyNewText);
}

@Override
protected void checkSubclass() {
    // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
}
}
```